# Migrating from Skype 4.2 to 4.3 on Ubuntu

Tags: skype

I have a lot of history in Skype v 4.2, but now it is deprecated cause of "cloud" conversations in new Skype versions. Now I installed Skype 4.3.0.37-1 on Ubuntu 14.04 (and my co-worker on his Debian 7) and I wondered I loss all history before 20th may 2014. How can I to integrate old history (I backuped ~/.Skype folder) to new Skype?

Comment: Did you delete the old skype folder? Maybe Skype now is in .skype instead of .Skype?

Comment: I renamed it. No, it creates .Skype folder too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try merging two databases with [Skyperious](https://suurjaak.github.io/Skyperious/).

Now, Skype might refuse to start due to malformed old messages. Open terminal, intall `sqlite3` if necessary and:

```
sqlite3 ~/.Skype/[username]/main.db
> UPDATE Messages SET body_xml=substr(body_xml,instr(body_xml,'<files')) WHERE type=68 AND body_xml LIKE 'posted%';
> UPDATE Messages SET body_xml=substr(body_xml,instr(body_xml,'<files')) WHERE type=68 AND body_xml LIKE 'sent file%';
> .quit
```

If it still does not start (very likely if you are using non-English version of Skype), you can try running following query in `sqlite3` and look through results to find other types of entries worth fixing:

```
SELECT Messages SET body_xml=substr(body_xml,instr(body_xml,'<files')) WHERE type=68
```

Answer (score 0):

I restored the history of past chat. Steps are given below:

1. Before installing new skype take backup of old skype folder from your home location. Folder is named as **.Skype** and rename it to **.Skype.old**
2. Install the new skype. It will create new folder named **.Skype**
3. Now visit your backup folder. i.e **.Skype.old** and there will be the folder having name as your skype username. Copy this folder and paste into **.Skype** folder.
4. Restart your skype and your chat history will be restored.